# How to use pickr color picker vanilla JS library within a React component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to use a color picker library called [pickr](https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr) in a react.js project.

How can I add the library to my react.js component ?

- I imported the library : `@simonwep/pickr`
- Then I imported the classic theme : `@simonwep/pickr/dist/themes/classic.min.css`
- Created a function called `ColorPicker` and pasted some code from the github repository in it
- That function returns a div tag containing the parameter : `className="color-picker"`

here is the source code :

```
import React from 'react';
import Pickr from '@simonwep/pickr';
import '@simonwep/pickr/dist/themes/classic.min.css';


export default function ColorPicker() {
const pickr = Pickr.create({
    el: '.color-picker',
    theme: 'classic', // or 'monolith', or 'nano'

    swatches: [
        'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
        'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
        'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
        'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
        'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
        'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
        'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
        'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
        'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75)',
        'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.8)',
        'rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.85)',
        'rgba(205, 220, 57, 0.9)',
        'rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.95)',
        'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
    ],

    components: {

        // Main components
        preview: true,
        opacity: true,
        hue: true,

        // Input / output Options
        interaction: {
            hex: false,
            rgba: true,
            hsla: false,
            hsva: false,
            cmyk: false,
            input: true,
            clear: true,
            save: true
        }
    }
});
return(
<div className="color-picker"></div>
)
  }
```

This is the error message that I get :

> TypeError: Unable to get property 'parentNode' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the following line

```
el: '.color-picker',
```

You are trying to get a reference the div element with the className="color-picker". But this element will not exist yet, as the component has not rendered. The render function will be called AFTER you are trying the get a reference to your div. So in order to fix this, you can use one of reacts lifecylce methods like componentDidMount

```
componentDidMount(){
  Pickr.create({
   el: '.color-picker',
   theme: 'classic', // or 'monolith', or 'nano'
   .... //rest of your code
}
```

In order for this to work though you need to make sure you are creating a react component rather than a simple javascript function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class ColorPicker extends Component { 

   ....

   componentDidMount(){
     const pickr = Pickr.create({
     el: '.color-picker',
     theme: 'classic', // or 'monolith', or 'nano'
      ...//rest of your code
   } 

   render(){
     return(
       <div className="color-picker"></div>
     )
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! followed your instructions and the problem was solved!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Happy coding!

Comment: Hey SirJCube! I want to use 3 color pickers in the same page do you know how can I add 2 more color pickers ? Thanks again!

Comment: I have not worked with the picker library that you are using before, but I would assume that you would need 3 different divs that each have their own unique className (or a unique id might be even better).  Then you would have to call the Picker.create( .... ) function 3 times, each time passing in a different element via the el: property

Comment: Yo Ala Ben Aicha, have a look at this from the Pickr github page, exactly what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/Simonwep/9ghk71c3/

Answer (score 1):

As the other replied said, you have to call the method after the first render, so that the element exists when the function is called.

You can use a class component and `componentDidMount` for that, or you can use a function component with hooks such as `useEffect` that control function component lifecycles.